# ImageBackground is not wrapping the stack.navigator and the stack.screens are not visible. (@react-navigation/stack": "^5.10.0 ) React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have multiple screens with the same background. I thought of having the ImageBackground in the Navigation file itself. But somehow the screens are not visible.

Here is the code

```
<ImageBackground style={styles.imageContainer} source={pic1}>
   <Stack.Navigator>
     <Stack.Screen name="screen1" component="Screen1" />
   <Stack.Navigator>
</ImageBackground>



    imageContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    alignItems: 'center',
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
```

Style also included

This is not working. Screen1 is not displayed but the background is properly displayed.

I also tried giving the `cardStyle` for the navigator as `backgroundColor:"transparent"`, even tried `backgroundColor:"transperent"` but nothing is working.

Thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use themes for this and set the background as transparent.

Import defaulttheme

```
import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

Update background color

```
const MyTheme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    primary: 'rgb(255, 45, 85)',
    background: 'transparent',
  },
};
```

And wrap the navigation container like this.

```
export default function App() {
  const image = { uri: 'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png' };
  return (
    <ImageBackground
      source={image}
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        resizeMode: 'cover',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}>
      <NavigationContainer theme={MyTheme}>
        <MyStack />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}
```

You can check the sample snack here
[https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/createstacknavigator-|-react-navigation](https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/createstacknavigator-%7C-react-navigation)

Comment: What if we have multiple sets of screens and each group has a different background Image? Can we use the same method? 
Using createSwitchNavigator..

Comment: i tried wrapping the navigator inside a imagebackground and it worked fine only thing is we'll have to set the transparency at root level just like i did

Comment: Ok, this will help a lot. Thanks once again!!