# Set ImageBackground using Stack Navigator

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

**What I'm facing:**

I have a `StackNavigator` in which I want to set a `ImageBacgkround` to all it's children screens. The problem is, I've already setted my StackNavigator `cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' }`, following [React Navigation Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#cardstyle), and wrapped it inside a `ImageBackground` but still can't get it working.

**What I've tried:**

```js
//My navigator component is more complex, but the concept looks something like this
//for both navigators
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const MyStackNavigator = () => (
  <ImageBackground source=('../assets/my-background.png') resizeMode='cover' style={{flex: 1}}>
    //If I change BackgroundColor to 'red' or anything like that, it works fine
    //so I think the problem isn't related to styling properties 
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{cardStyle: { BackgroundColor: 'transparent' } }}>
      <Stack.Screen name='Screen1' component={Component1}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='Screen2' component={Component2}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='Screen3' component={Component3}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </ImageBackground>
);

export default App() => (
  <MyStackNavigator />
);
```

I've done the same thing in a `DrawerNavigator` inside my navigator component passing `sceneContainerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' } }}` and it actually works. It seems like my StackNavigator ain't rendering it's parent components correctly.

**One of my StackNavigator's screens:**

[image: Screen inside StackNavigator]

**One of my DrawerNavigator's screens:**

[image: Screen inside DrawerNavigator]

Both navigator's screens layout are wrapped in a transparent container `View`, so as you can see, the drawer screen is rendering background correctly but the stack screen isn't. Maybe I'm passing wrong props to my StackNavigator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well with react-navigation 6 you can use the theming option to customize the look for the background to be transparent (Default is `rgb(242,242,242)`) use a NavigatorContainer to apply the theme

[here is an answer that may help](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7114#issuecomment-897401297)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I said in the code, I can set backGroundColor to any color, even rgba values, so I don't think the problem is related to styling.

Comment: The link has the code for stack navigator with Imagebackground have you checked that?

Comment: Yes, my code is very similar to the code of the link, except for the styling method (which isn't the cause of my problem).

Comment: Could you please test applying your image for each screen like this: `<Stack.Screen 
    name='Home' 
    component={HomeScreen} 
    options={{ 
      title: <Image style={{ width: 250, height: 50 }}
      source = require('../images/yourimage.png')}/> 
    }}
 />` . I mean using image source for each screen separately, without wrapping stack in a `<ImageBackground`.

Comment: I tested it in one of my stack navigators and, unfortunately, still didn't work.

Comment: @RANJANKUMARSINGH Tested your solution again and it worked! Also got some help from (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64570748/16689004), but thanks anyway.